# How can I get fn({param}) of the param type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, core-motion, emotion

I'm using raw [emotion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emotion) package `npm i emotion` and bumped to this question.

If I do this

```js
import { css } from 'emotion';

const test = css({
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
})
```

If I hover the `boxSizing`, VSCode tells me that `boxSizing` type is

```
"border-box" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "content-box" | BoxSizingProperty[] | undefined
```

Now, I want to retrieve those type, resulting in this

```
type result = "border-box" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "content-box" | BoxSizingProperty[] | undefined
```

Is there any utility method I can use to retrieve those types?

If I can just do

```
import { css } from 'emotion';

type result = someUtility<typeof css, 'boxSizing'>
```

Is it possible to do this without installing any new npm package? I know emotion use `csstype` package for typings under the hood.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question, but if what you want its the boxSizing type, you can get it from
import { BoxSizingProperty } from "csstype";

Comment: But I will have to install the exactly csstype version of emotion is using, and emotion is using old csstype version as dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to install another package, here's what you can do:

```
import { ObjectInterpolation } from 'emotion'

type BoxSizing = ObjectInterpolation<undefined>['boxSizing'] // type BoxSizing = "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "border-box" | "content-box" | BoxSizingProperty[] | undefined
```

You may also find the [`Parameters` generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) useful, although I don't believe it quite works here since `Interpolation<T>` is a union type of several items. Here's an example of how this can be used in another function:

```js
const example = (params: { boxSizing: 'border-box' }) => undefined

type BoxSizing = Parameters<typeof example>[0]['boxSizing']
```